# Undefined symbol error for class with header and cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, class

I'm using Qt to build an application and every time I construct my command class, it throws an undefined symbol for architecture error. Which looks like this

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Command::getResultText()", referenced from:
  MainWindow::handleButton() in mainwindow.o
 "Command::Command(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
  MainWindow::handleButton() in mainwindow.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've included the command.h header file and this is what it looks like.

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

class Command {

std::string commandText;
std::string resultText = "";
int returnCode = 0;

public:
  Command(std::string toExecute);
  ~Command(void){};
  void executeCode();
  std::string getResultText();
  int getReturnCode();
};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation of this class:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "command.h"

using namespace boost::process;
using namespace std;

Command::Command(string toExecute) {
  this->commandText = toExecute;
}

void Command::executeCode() {
  ipstream pipe_stream;
  child c;
  string line;
  try {

   c = child(this->commandText, (std_out & std_err) > pipe_stream);
   while (pipe_stream && std::getline(pipe_stream, line) && !line.empty())
    std::cerr << line << std::endl;

    this ->returnCode = 0;


} catch (...){
  printf("Please enter a valid command");
  this->returnCode = -1;
}
c.wait();

}

string Command::getResultText() {
  return resultText;
}

int Command::getReturnCode() {
  return returnCode;
}
```

Comment: Do you get a similar error when invoking the other functions in that class? If yes, the cpp file's probably not being compiled or passed to the linker..

Comment: Yes, pretty much every function is giving that error when called upon.

Comment: Then the implementation file is almost certainly not being included in the build instructions. I'm not familiar with the QT build tools, but if it is a GUI, there will probably be an Add File option somewhere.